# loop through array variable and create nodes using xsl

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am creating an xml file through the xsl

I have an xsl variable which gets the value as a string array from a C# method in the included scripts.
Now i need to loop through the array variable and create xml nodes.
Following is my code.

```
<xsl:variable name="_arrInspectionTimes" select="(scripts:GetInspectionTime(normalize-space(openhouses/openhouse/openhouse_start), normalize-space(openhouses/openhouse/openhouse_end)))">
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:element name="inspectionTimes">
    <xsl:for-each select="$_arrInspectionTimes">
          <xsl:element name="inspection">
               <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="."/>
         </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

I am not able to render the nodes inside the loop. Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the output? is it blank or is it an error? can you confirm if values are returned in _arrInspectionTimes?

Comment: output is simply <inspectionTimes/> closed node. I confirmed the returned values in the string[] they are proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most XSLT processors interfacing with C# will allow you to pass in a set of XML nodes in their native data model (e.g. `XPathNodeIterator` or `XPathNavigator` for Microsoft's `XslCompiledTransform`) but support to C# arrays is less likely. So find out which .NET XSLT processor you use and check its documentation for the types of data you can pass from an extension function to XSLT to process it in XSLT. For instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxaw5z5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx shows that from C# you can pass in an XPathNavigator or XPathNodeIterator to process nodes in XslCompiledTransform. That means instead of writing an extension function returning `string[]` write one returning `XPathNodeIterator` e.g.

```
public XPathNodeIterator GetInspectionTime (...) 
{
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("root"));
  foreach (string value in yourArray) 
  {
    XmlElement item = doc.CreateElement("item");
    item.InnerText = value;
    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(item);
  }
  return doc.CreateNavigator().Select("/root/item");
}
```

Comment: Hello Martin, Thanks for the information, but does this mean that i can not create the xml node in the way i have provided?

Comment: I can't tell you anything precise without knowing which XSLT processor you use. If you use `XslCompiledTransform` then it does not support passing a C# string array to XSLT, you will need to pass in XPathNavigator or XPathNodeIterator. If you use a different XSLT processor things might be different but we can't help with concrete code if you don't tell us which XSLT processor you use. The sample I posted applies to `XslCompiledTransform` and changes to be made on the C# side of the code, the XSLT could remain as it is in your sample.

Comment: I would like to give you the version and vendor info regarding the processor here: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  extension-element-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:scripts="urn:scripts.this"> The C# script i have used is inside another xsl and i have used  <msxsl:script> which contains all my C# methods inside CDATA. This means it will not support returning a string[] to my xslt??

Comment: Do you use `XslCompiledTransform` as the XSLT processor or not?

Comment: Then see the documentation and the sample I posted, you can't process a C# array in XSLT with XslCompiledTransform, you need to pass in an XPathNodeIterator or XPathNavigator.